# Confused about diffraction/interference

Tags: optics, interference, diffraction

I got confused when I was studying the interference patterns that arise in a film when light come from the slits.
It is said that a require condition to the interference occurs using slits, is that $1>\lambda/d>>0$, where i used >>0 meaning that $\lambda/d$ is not too low, even so it is not greater than one.

Now, I remember that a condition for diffraction to occur is that $\lambda > d$. Now, you can see the confusion arising: if it matches the condition for one event, it can't match the other condition. This give rise to some question.

Or the interference involving slits do not occurs due to the diffraction, in another words, actually there are no diffraction occuring in the slits, and if so, I have understood the phenomenon wrong my whole life.

Or the condition that $\lambda > d$ is not really necessary to "strong diffraction" occurs, and so the diffraciton that occurs at the slit, if we talk about water waves incident on a slit, for example, would almost not be notable.

Could you help me to clarify these conditions that can't be both true at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

> Could you help me to clarify these conditions that can't be both true at the same time?

The conditions can indeed both be true at the same time. The problem is that you are using the same variable, $d$, to represent two different things.

Your first $d$ is the distance between slits. So the distance between slits does need to be larger than a wavelength (but not excessively large).

Your second $d$ is the width of the slits themselves. So each slit needs to be thinner than a wavelength.

It is easily possible to have two slits where each slit is smaller than a wavelength and their separation is larger than a wavelength. This example indicates why it is important to not just blindly throw formulas around. It is essential to know the physical meaning of each formula and the assumptions/restrictions used in obtaining it.